# Is there an easy way to put my entire installation of PyCharm and WinPython on a USB stick?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, portable-applications

I want to have a self-contained installation of python on a USB stick as I don't have enough room on my laptop to install anaconda etc. 
This will also be useful as I use different machines that can't have software installed on them.

I know that multiple settings must be changed for this to work but there is very little information about this and I don't have any experience in changing program files/settings.

I already have both WinPython and PyCharm installed on the USB stick but I have not yet changed any settings.

Comment: WinPython does not need installation so you're ok. You can also download PyCharm Portable and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm only using PyCharm as that's what a friend recommended - it there another IDE/text editor that's better? I've used and liked Atom and Sublime 3 before.

Comment: There is PyCharm that needs no installation: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pycharm-portable/

Comment: VScode+Python-vscode extension is the closest  alternative to PyCharm, a little more Atom/Sublime, and a little less specific to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is older, but I ran into this same question days ago.

I took a fresh USB stick and installed the latest Python onto it, instead of letting Python install to the default Windows directory. Then, I installed Pycharm the same way to my USB stick, with no issue.

Once I was inside of Pycharm, the bottom right hand corner of the screen said "No Interpreter." I clicked that and navigated my way to the flash drive and selected where Python was.

So far, I have had absolutely no issue using it and learning more about Python on the go!